# Is the range of a bounded linear functional closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be an inner product space and $f$ be a bounded linear functional $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Is $ran f$ a closed subspace of $X$?

I have found that $ker f$ is a closed subspace of $X$, but have no idea for the range of $f$.

Any hint will be most appreciated.

Comment: You're implying the range of a linear functional on $X$ is a subspace of $X$, nonsense.

Comment: @user444628: I think you want the range of $f$ to be a closed subspace of $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: @user444628: You might need to see Closed Graph Theorem.

Comment: @Idonknow  Oh thank you so much. So what is an example of a functional whose range is not a subspace?

Comment: I think you mean bounded linear operator rather than bounded linear functional.

Comment: @jgon I mean a bounded linear functional.

Comment: @user444628 I'm very confused by what you're asking then, so I'll ask my question again without using words that could be confused. Do you mean that $f : X\to X$, or $f : X\to \Bbb{K}$ where $\Bbb{K}$ is the field you're working over. If it's indeed the latter, you should understand our confusion.

Comment: @jgon Oh so sorry for me making the mistake. I mean a bounded linear functional from X to \mathbb{C}.

Comment: Then the range is either 0 or $\Bbb{C}$, which are certainly closed subspaces of $\Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of a (complex) linear functional is indeed a subspace and has dimension over C of either 0 or 1 .If 0 then the range of f is (0) ,if 1 then the range of f is C .in both cases closed in C